# Couldn't load file: assets/libgdx128.png

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm building a game in LibGDX and have began adding visual aspects of the game such as the logo. Considering that I've been using the default libgdxXXX.png files as placeholders for my logo, and that I'm replacing them with my logo, I didn't feel it had any more purpose in my program. I decide to delete it; but it decide to not compile and come up with this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: assets/libgdx128.png
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:148)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:196)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:142)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: assets/libgdx128.png (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:145)
... 3 more
```

Somehow, when I return the files from the Trash (I use Linux), it works again! I have checked my code and found nothing I wrote referred to those files. When I deleted the files 1 by 1, the error changes from libgdx128.png to libgdx64.png to libgdx32.png to libgdx16.png respectively. I have changed all the references from libgdx128.png to my logo.png in my code; yet when I try to delete the libgdx logo and run my program, it fails to compile! Any ideas?

Comment: Because of the 128, 64, 32 it sounds like you are doing something for android? The libgdx128.png could be referenced in the manifest file maybe as the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my problem. I forgot all about this code at DesktopLauncher.java:

```
for (int size : new int[] { 128, 64, 32, 16 }) {
    configuration.addIcon("assets/libgdx" + size + ".png", FileType.Internal);
}
```

I did not know it was referencing to the files I have deleted. The `configuration.addIcon();` was the code setting the program icon - similar to how a favicon works. I will be adding my own icon now that I know what the code does.

Hope this helps anyone else confused about the error.